# Making a threading system in lua

Tags: multithreading, lua

So I have been working with coroutines for a little while and I'm sort of having trouble trying to make what I want. I want a class that I can access objectivley creating objects as tasks or processes. I think showing you code would be irrelevant and its not what I want either. So I'm just going to show you how i want the functionality

```
local task1 = Tasker.newTask(function()
  while true do 
    print("task 1")
  end
end)

local task2 = Tasker.newTask(function()
  while true do 
    print("task 2")
  end
end)

task1:start()
task2:start()
```

This way I can run multiple tasks at once, I want to be able to add new tasks when ever during runtime. Also I would like a way to stop the tasks also for example:

```
task2:stop()
```

But I don't want the stop command to entirely delete the task instance, only stop the task itself so I can invoke

```
task2:start()
```

Then maybe I could use a command to delete it.

```
task2:delete()
```

This would be very helpful and thank you for help if you need more info please ask. Also i posted this on my phone so there may be typos and formatting issues

Answer (score 2):

Lua doesn't natively support operating system threads, i.e. preemptive multitasking.

You can use coroutines to implement your own cooperative "threads", but each thread must relinquish control before another can do anything.

```
local task1 = Tasker.newTask(function()
  while true do 
    print("task 1")
    coroutine.yield()
  end
end)

local task2 = Tasker.newTask(function()
  while true do 
    print("task 2")
    coroutine.yield()
  end
end)
```

Your Tasker class must take the task function and wrap it in a coroutine, then take care of calling `coroutine.resume` on them. Operations like `stop` and `start` would set flags on the task that tell Tasker whether or not to resume that particular coroutine in the main loop.

Comment: So every iteration of any loop needs a yeild and the tasker class needs to resume it?

Comment: Not *necessarily* every iteration. Perhaps the task wants to do 5 iterations before handing control back. The point is that it needs to yield control. If it doesn't yield or return, then it has control *forever*. It won't be preempted, as with an operating system thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via C. You might be able to use [LuaLanes and Linda objects](http://cmr.github.io/lanes/).